# Sigmoid function in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am taking a probability and statistics course and I wanted to draw a logistic regression graph, so I figured I'd use LaTeX for this. This is my first time using it so I am having a bit of trouble. I kind of want my graph to look something like this (see image 1) but instead I get an output like this (see image 2). I have defined the sigmoid function and the domains but it seems a bit messed up. Does anyone have a nice fix for this? This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, width=10cm}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=newest}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    inner axis line style={->},
    xlabel={$x$ Household's income [KSEK]},
    ylabel={$y$ Probability of purchasing a car},
    ytick={0,0.5,...,1},
    xtick={0,10,...,60},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=60,
]

\addplot[color=black, thick, mark=*] coordinates {
            (5, 0.02)
            (8, 0.02)
            (11, 0.02)
            (15, 0.02)
            (17, 0.02)
            (22, 0.02)
            (24, 0.02)
            (34, 0.02)
        };

\addplot[color=black, thick, mark=*] coordinates {
            (24, 0.98)
            (33, 0.98)
            (37, 0.98)
            (45, 0.98)
            (47, 0.98)
            (50, 0.98)
            (52, 0.98)
            (55, 0.98)
        };
        
\addplot[color=black] coordinates {
            (0, 0.5)
            (60, 0.5)
        };

\addplot [domain=0.5:59.5, samples=100,
          thick, color=black] {1/(1+exp(-x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: IMAGE 1]

[image: IMAGE 2]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Your sigmoid is centered around zero instead of 30. (I guess that's what you want?) That is, try plotting `1/(1+exp(-x+30)` instead.